# Find value in an embedded array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I find a value in the collection "inputs" based on this schema:

```
var inputJournalSchema = new Schema({
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    inputs: [{ key: String, value: String}]
});
```

Basically, I'd like to check whether there is an element with a specifific key and if so, at which index position.

But how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Once an object has been created with the schema:

```
object.inputs[0].key;
```

Here is a simple way to find a specific key, assuming objects are stored in an array. If the objects are not stored in array the loop is not needed.

```
var findThis = 1;
var objects = [{}, {}, {}, {}];

objects.forEach(function (object) {
    object.inputs.forEach(function (input, index) {
        if (input.key == findThis) {
            // logic for once found here
            console.log(index);
        }
    });
});
```

This code could also be wrapped in a function that returns the index using the key as an argument:

```
function findIndex (objects, key) {
    objects.forEach(function (object) {
        object.inputs.forEach(function (input, index) {
            if (input.key == key) {
                // logic for once found here
                return index;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: But that's simply iterating over the array checking for matches. Is there no built-in find method?